# Why is the question being asked after giving an answer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a game where the user is told which button to randomly select. However, at the moment, the question is being asked after I have selected a button so they never match.

Can anyone advise on why this is the case?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Guitar")
root.grid()

def check(whichButton,val):
    print("Answer we are looking for was "+val)
    print("The button pressed was: " + str(whichButton))
    
    if val == whichButton:
        print("They match")
    else:
        print("They Dont")
    
def buttonA(event):
    import random
    butts = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F' , 'G']
    value = random.choice(butts)
    print(value)
    updateDisplay(value)
    check("A",value)
    
def buttonB(event):
    import random
    butts = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F' , 'G']
    value = random.choice(butts)
    print(value)
    updateDisplay(value)
    check("B",value)
    
def updateDisplay(myString):
    displayVariable.set("Please press Button " + myString)

button_1 = Button(root, text="A String")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>",buttonA)
button_1.pack()

button_2 = Button(root, text="B String")
button_2.bind("<Button-1>",buttonB)
button_2.pack()

displayVariable = StringVar()
displayLabel = Label(root, textvariable=displayVariable)
displayLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: roll `value` outside of buttonA/B methods?

Comment: You need to call `updateDisplay` *before* pressing a button, so you can't have the (first) call inside either button callback.

Comment: Aside: Don't put `import` statements inside functions, put them at the beginning of the script.

Comment: You need a third button that calls `updateDisplay()`. `updateDisplay()` should make the random choice. It can save this in a global variable that you check in the functions for buttons A and B.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: rollback.

> Why is the question being asked after giving an answer?

The reasoning why not getting **They match**, is because you're `tk.StringVar()`. It is not good ideas. I removed it.

@Barmar saying, it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports.

- At the start, you need to display which button.
- Use constant to declare variable outside. So no need to duplicate.
- Add two `Label` widgets to update using `.configure`.
- Use `f-string` and `r-string` format. The `r-string` format merely for text not
  variable.
- Use `return` instead of `if-elif-else`.

Snippet modified, but not much:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Guitar")
root.grid()

butts = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F' , 'G']

def check(whichButton,val):
    print(r"Answer we are looking for was "+ val)
    print(r"The button pressed was: " + str(whichButton))
    
    display_result.configure(text=f"Answer we are looking for was {val}, \n The button pressed was: {str(whichButton)}")

    if val == whichButton:
        return dont_match_label.configure(text=r"They match")
    return dont_match_label.configure(text=r"They Dont")
    
def buttonA(event):
    value = random.choice(butts)
    print(value)
    updateDisplay(value)
    check("A", value)
    button_2.configure(text=f'{value} String')
    
def buttonB(event):     
    value = random.choice(butts)
    print(value)
    updateDisplay(value)
    check("B", value)
    button_1.configure(text=f'{value} String')
    
def updateDisplay(myString):
    displayLabel.configure(text=f"Please press Button {myString}"  )

button_1 = tk.Button(root, text=r"A String")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>",buttonA)
button_1.pack()

button_2 = tk.Button(root, text=r"B String")
button_2.bind("<Button-1>",buttonB)
button_2.pack()

#displayVariable = tk.StringVar()
displayLabel = tk.Label(root, text=r"Please press Button  A or B")
displayLabel.pack()

display_result = tk.Label(root)
display_result.pack()

dont_match_label = tk.Label(root)
dont_match_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_. Ideally, our goal here is to [build a long-tail FAQ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) -- a collection of questions and answers likely to be helpful to other people in the future -- so part of why we encourage questions to be narrow and specific is not just to make answering them easier, but also to make the answers _more useful to future readers_.

Comment: Nobody else is going to have the exact questions this OP does here; answering a question in this state means your answer is _less useful_ than it would have been if you'd held out for the question to be narrowed (to eliminate everything not specific to an individual technical problem underlying the OP's larger issue) first.

Comment: Thank for link. I wasn't aware.